# Grid Panel and Combo box same store - ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a grid panel and one of the columns in the grid panel has a combo box editor and it uses the same store as the grid panel. The grid panel has paging and it displays the data as required. But when the combo box is clicked,  on first click the combo box displays first page records only. When clicked again, it displays all records without paging which is the desired result. Is there any way, I can make the combo box to load properly on first click it self. I have paging related setup in the back end and I send an extra param which decides to the appropriate paging or no paging process.

Comment: Add some good or, even better, great a Sencha Fiddle to show us what you are doing.

Comment: Since grid paging is affecting the underlying store, I wonder why your grid does not break when you open the combo. Normally, you would need two stores if you want both a paginated and an unpaginated (or a filtered and an unfiltered, or a sorted and an unsorted...) component.